# Matlab 2011a outperforms 2015b

Tags: matlab, time

I have a very weird time difference in matlab. The following code (I know it is a bit messy) runs extremely faster on matlab 2011a (average time for each iteration 2.5 secs), while on matlab 2015b it need on average 25 secs! Any suggestions why this could be happening? It would be convinient, if I could get this time in matlab 2015b.

```
for k = 1:length(z),
      tic;  
      file = z(k).name; 
      sep = fopen([pathf filesep file],'r');
  frewind(sep)
  icc = 1;
  illt=1;
  data = [];
  while 1
    h = fgetl(sep);

    if illt==10  
        LAT(k)=str2num(h(19:20)) + str2num(h(22:26))/60;
    elseif illt==11
        LON(k)=- (str2num(h(20:22)) + str2num(h(24:28))/60);
    elseif illt==12
        TIME(k)=datenum(h(21:40));
    end
    if ~ischar(h), break; 
    end
    if numel(h)==0 || strcmp(h(1),'#') || strcmp(h(1),'*')
        illt=illt+1;
    else
      data(icc,:) = str2num(h);
      icc = icc+1;
    end
  end

  [mm nn]=size(data);
  iq0 = find(diff(data(:,4)) <=0);

  iq=iq0;


  q=1;
  while data(q,4)<6 ,  q=q+1; end
  position=q;
  c=1;
  for qq=position:iq
  TEMP1(c,k)=data(qq,2);
  COND1(c,k)=data(qq,3);
  PRESS1(c,k)=data(qq,4);
  OOO1(c,k)=data(qq,16);     
  PTEMP1(c,k)=data(qq,9);
  PTEMP2(c,k)=data(qq,19);
  SALIN1(c,k)=data(qq,8);
  SALIN2(c,k)=data(qq,20);
  PDEN1(c,k)=data(qq,15); % sigma-theta, pot. density...
  % with effect of adiabatic cooling/heating effect...
  %[using potential temperature] and the pressure effect removed
  PDEN2(c,k)=data(qq,17);  % sigma-t, pot. density at atm. pressure
  c=c+1;
  end
toc;
end
```

Comment: Use `profile` to identify the problem. You can generate a HTML-Report from both versions and upload it somewhere if you have problems identifying the issue.

Comment: Do you run the two versions on the same machine? If yes, do the two version access the same data stored in the same place?

Comment: r2015b a new JIT engine was introduced - Mathworks stated that most actions are faster but a few are slower - you may be unlucky...

Comment: @CST-Link yes I run them in the same machine and on the same files. The code is copy pasted, 0 changes. and the tic toc results are 10 times slower...

Comment: @matlabgui: That might be a cause. By the way, it was not only JIT being replaced, [large parts of the execution engine where reimplemented](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-execution-engine/?refresh=true)